# JQUERY/HTML - show/hide content after selecting value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I want to show my content after selecting value in the drop down here what I have is  `Personal` which if you select the content will change. but what i have in content is `hide` so when I just select a value on the drop down that is the time the content will show.

my ***Dropdown***

```
  <select name="messagetype" id="messagetype" class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" title="News Type" data-size="7" onchange="fun_showtextbox()">
                                            <option disabled="">Select Receipt</option>
                                            <option value="All">Send to all</option>
                                            <option value="Personal">Send to Personal</option>

                                        </select>
```

my Content `div`

```
<div id="sectiontohide" style="display:none;" id="mobileno_textbox">
      <p>Show Content</p>
</div
```

my ***Javascrip/Jquery***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function fun_showtextbox(){

        var select_status=$('#messagetype').val();

                if(select_status == 'Personal')
                {
                        $('#mobileno_textbox').show();        
                }
                else
                {
                        $('#mobileno_textbox').hide();
                }
        }

</script>
```

my ***Link***

```
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: It is not showing the content when I select the value nothing change , the content is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div has 2 ids

```
<div id="sectiontohide" style="display:none;" id="mobileno_textbox">
  <p>Show Content</p>
</div>
```

Try to fix that, and run the code again. All you need to do is simply remove the `sectiontohide` id because the other one is already being used.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Haha, im lauging at it rn. thanks sir :) didnt noticed that one ccoming haha

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like this 
var select_status = $(this).val();

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#messagetype').on('change', function() {

if(this.value=="Personal")
{

$('#mobileno_textbox').show();  
}
else
{

   $('#mobileno_textbox').hide();  
}
});

});
</script>


<select name="messagetype" id="messagetype" class="selectpicker" data-style="select- 
with-transition" title="News Type" data-size="7" >
                                        <option disabled="">Select Receipt</option>
                                        <option value="All">Send to all</option>
                                        <option value="Personal">Send to 
Personal</option>

                                    </select>
<div style="display:none"  id="mobileno_textbox"> <p>Show Content</p></div>
```